# Cartoon or anime featuring identical robots wearing hats and walking in ranks

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

At 0:57 there is some animation, might be from some anime. So I was wondering which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from *The Animatrix* (2001), specifically "The Second Renaissance, Part One". You can see them at 1'43 in the following video.

As its name indicates, *The Animatrix* is animated material related to *The Matrix*'s backstory.

---

Found by reverse-imaging [this cropped picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be5Kj.jpg).